# Mounting new ext4 to /mnt and editing /etc/fstab file

Tags: mount, ext4, automounting

I have a basic DOS/MBR partition scheme with the partitions

```
/dev/sda1 /boot
/dev/sda2 /
/dev/sda swap
/dev/sda6 /home
```

I am needing to mount an ext4 partition to /mnt, edit the etc/fstab file and ensure the filesystem will be mounted with every boot, and copy the etc/fstab file to /mnt directory. I am newer to Linux and am still trying to figure out the steps and code to most configurations. I am having trouble figuring out which partitions I should add into the etc/fstab file

Comment: I stopped using MBR(msdos) 10 years ago on all Linux only drives. Only Windows  requires MBR for BIOS boot. You cannot have swap mounted at /dev/sda, it must be one of your partitions? I do not suggest mounting at /mnt, but at /mnt/data or whatever mount name or label you like. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: Please verify your post... As @oldfred noted, you cannot have `/dev/sda` mounted as `swap` because `/dev/sda` (without a number after it) means the entire disk--which includes any partitions and operating systems installed. (swap space has it's own disk structures it needs... but otherwise, you don't want swap space to overwrite your installed operating system...)

Answer (score 2):

You need knew the UUID from partition, Use the command below:

```
$ sudo blkid
```

To list all the partitions and their UUIDs, run the following command:
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
Then you have insert the an line in /etc/fstab, like bellow:

```
UUID=41c22818-fbad-4da6-8196-c816df0b7aa8  /mnt      ext4    defaults,errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

You can change the values on line above after ext4.

To send file to /mnt, you can insert an input  on crontab, like below:
Create the script and change the permissions:

```
#>/home/user/test.sh && chmod +x /home/user/test.sh
```

Insert in crontab this new input:

```
#crontab -e
@reboot  /home/user/test.sh
```

Script Content:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -p /etc/fstab /mnt
```